# Cypress - getState() function always returning initialState when invoked from cypress test

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, cypress, redux-toolkit

I am testing my react-redux app using cypress following [this blog](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/11/14/testing-redux-store/#a-good-start):

The issue is that when I am invoking getState from `window.store` it is always returning the initial state.

```
cy.window()
        .its("store")
        .invoke("getState")
        .then((state) => {
            expect(state.requiredKey).to.have.length(1)
        })
```

Expected behaviour is that the getState() should return me my current redux store. I am following all the steps as mentioned in blog.

Can anyone help me out. Let me know if more details are required.

I am using redux-toolkit and redux-saga.

This is `cypress.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  component: {

    supportFile : "cypress/support/**/*.cy.{jsx,tsx,js,ts}",
    devServer: {
      framework: "create-react-app",
      bundler: "webpack",
    },
  },

  e2e: {
    baseUrl:"http://localhost:3000",
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Off topic: why use an end-to-end testing framework to test internal state management of your app? I know the first paragraph of the blog post you linked mentions that this is possible, but I'd argue that it isn't a good idea. I'd rather write integration tests for this. The "end" that represents the human input in "end-to-end" loses its meaning if you "reach into the application" as the blog post says. Littering the code with stuff like `if (window.Cypress) { window.store = store }` is also quite ugly. With unit or integration tests you don't have jump through such hoops.